# Modifying an array during iteration

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, immutability

Consider the excerpt:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.each { |e| a.shift ; p e  ;  p a }
```

that outputs:

```
1
[2, 3, 4, 5]
3
[3, 4, 5]
5
[4, 5]
```

It reveals that the implementation of `each` is done in terms of an index (`1`  is the element at position `0` when printed, `3`  is the element at `1` when printed, and `5` is the element at position `2` when printed).

An alternative would be to print `1`, `2`, `3`.

Is this behaviour intended? Or is it just implementation detail, and it is possible that someday `Array` gets reimplemented and this behavior may change?

Comment: That sort of thing happens when you remove elements from a collection over which you are enumerating. By contrast, `a.dup.each{ |e| a.shift ; p e  ;  p a }` prints `"1\n[2, 3, 4, 5\n2\n[3, 4, 5]\n3\n[4, 5]\n4\n[5]"`.

.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a well known behaviour.

It is likely that the behaviour is due to implementation reason, i.e., efficiency, etc.

But whether or not it is just implementation detail does not have much significance. Ruby developers are concerned about not breaking backward compatibility, and it is very unlikely that such basic behaviour will be altered. Even if they were to go on, they will have a reasonably long span of transition period.

Regardless of that, it is usually not good to modify an array during iteration from the point of view of readability. In the relevant cases, it is likely that you should duplicate the array.

Comment: They're fairly concerned about backwards compatibility with well-known behaviour, but with edge cases like this? You're right, not really.